# How to use SQL to do a group by with different dates?

Tags: sql, group-by

Lets say I have a table with the following columns:

- Qty, INTEGER
- SaleDate, DATETIME

I would now like to see this result:

```
Sold in the last 7 days | Sold in last 14 days
-----------------------------------------------------
10                      | 20
```

I can use a where clause to use **between**, however how would I get the qty sold for 7 and 14 days?

Comment: I'm confused by the `Qty` column in the output; do you want the actual totals sold in the last 7 and 14 days, or do you really want results grouped by quantity (i.e. how many quantities of 1 sold, how many quantities of 2 sold, etc.)?

Comment: Agree with Aaronaught: the aggregate/columns make no sense.

Comment: @gbn @Aaronaught I modified my output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter in the WHERE clause to get days 0 to -14. Then aggregate on days 0 to -7 separately.

```
SELECT
   ...,
   SUM(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 7days,
   COUNT(*) AS 14days
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   SaleDate >= DATEADD(day, -14, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(Qty), datediff(w, getdate(), SaleDate) as Period
from table
group by  datediff(ww, getdate(), SaleDate)
```

Comment: This counts week boundarys, not 7 days.
So fri to mon is one week but only 3 days, for example

Comment: Last 7 days, last 14 days, looks like week boundaries to me

Comment: Ok, monday to following wednesday = one week boundary but 
9 days. OP asked for 7 and 14 days. Do you not see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in MS T-SQL 2003

```
declare @whatever table(
    qty int,
    saledate datetime
)
insert into @whatever select 1, getdate()
insert into @whatever select 2, dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 2, dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -3, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -4, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -5, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -6, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -7, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -8, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -9, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 2, dateadd(dd, -10, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 2, dateadd(dd, -11, getdate())

insert into @whatever select 1, dateadd(dd, -15, getdate())
insert into @whatever select 2, dateadd(dd, -16, getdate())

select
        qty,
        sum(
            case
                when datediff(dd, saledate, getdate()) between 0 and 7 then 1
                else 0
            end
        ) as [Sold in last 7 days],
        sum(
            case
                when datediff(dd, saledate, getdate()) between 0 and 14 then 1
                else 0
            end
        ) as [Sold in last 14 days]
    from
        @whatever
    group by
        qty
;
```